# How to adapt bound text to div

Tags: html, css

I have two divs side by side. The problem is, when I have long bound text in one div, it overflows to the second.
here is an example:
http://jsfiddle.net/hjZ8F/1/

How to adapt?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is working version of your jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/hjZ8F/2/

Just add `word-wrap: break-word;` to the style attribute of the long span